# Weird behavior writing/reading simple binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm writing and reading on a binary file. I'm getting small errors when outputting the reads.

The strings are there but with little snippets like: (I"�U) (�U) appended to the end of ~30% of them

I'm using g++ compiler on Ubuntu

Simplified code:

```
struct Db_connection
{
    public:
        string name;
}

int Db_connection::write_config()
{
    ofstream config_f("config.dat", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out); //open file

    string str = name;
    int size = str.length();
    
    config_f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), sizeof(int)); // write size of string in int size chunk
    config_f.write(str.c_str(), size); //write string

    config_f.close();
    return 0;
}

Db_connection read_config()
{
    ifstream config_f("config.dat", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

    Db_connection return_obj;
    int size;
    string data;

    config_f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), sizeof(int)); // read string size
    char buffer[size];
    config_f.read(buffer, size); // read string
    data.assign(buffer);
    return_obj.name = data;

    return return_obj;
}
```

Is there anything obvious I am messing up? Does this have to do with Endian? I tried to minimize the code to it's absolute essentials

The actual code is more complex. I have a class holding vectors of 2 structs. 1 struct has four string members and the other has a string and bool. These fuctions are actually a member of and return (respectively) that class. The fuctions loop through the vectors writing struct members sequentially.

Two oddities:

1. To debug, I added outputs of the `size` and `data` variables on each iteration in both the read and write functions. `size` comes out accurate and consistent on both sides. `data` is accurate on the `write` side but with the weird special characters on the `read` side. I'm looking at outputs like:

```
Read Size: 12
Data: random addy2�U //the 12 human readable chars are there but with 2 extra symbols
```

2. The final chunk of data (a bool) comes out fine every time, so I don't think there is a file pointer issue. If its relevant: every `bool` and `int` is fine. Its just a portion of the strings.

Hopefully i'm making a bonehead mistake and this minimized code can be critiqued. The actual example would be too long.

Comment: First, stop using VLAs, even if they're supported by non-standard extension on your platform. Second, your write operation dumps the chars but no terminator, your read operation reads the chars, but sets no terminator. The `assign` method of `std::string` you're using expects a terminated string. You can fix that a number of ways, one easy way being `data = std::string(buffer, buffer+size);` . But as I said, ditch the VLAs and use a vector instead. Or better still, just direct-read into `data` after setup and access to the managed buffer therein, if your toolchain standard is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If I allocated a char array with the `new` command that would also be a VLA? To use a vector I would `push_back()` byte by byte into a vector<char>?

Comment: There is no place in modern c++ to use `operator new` whatsoever. If you need a temporary char vector of  size `size`, then `std::vector<char> buff(size);` would be sufficient. Then read into `buff.data()`, with no more than `size` bytes requested, and finally, `data = std::string(buff.begin(), buff.end());` No manually managed memory lifetime required; everything cleans up by itself. I'd still make sure your read request of `size` actually reads `size`, but that's another issue.

Comment: Great, thank you very much

Comment: Beware of storing types like `int` in binary.  This is not portable.  The size of this datatype is implementation-specific.  You should instead decide on the data size (e.g. 16, 32, 64 bits) and write it with an appropriate type (_i.e._ something from `<cstdint>` such as `uint32_t`).  Extra precaution is required to ensure endianness compatibility.  Properly-portable applications will choose both the right data type, and then create a method to read/write that data type in a chosen endianness.

Comment: Where does one learn these things? Blogs? Books? Time in industry? I took classes in C++ up to data structures and none of these concepts were mentioned. Thanks, I will use google to research the keywords you mentioned as well

Comment: Writing a binary `int` to your output will generate garbage characters no matter what you do.

Comment: Meaning the `write` and `read` functions should both use something like `<cstdint>` or `uint32_t`?

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to WhozCraig,

The following edit did, indeed, work:

```
Db_connection read_config()
{
    ifstream config_f("config.dat", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

    Db_connection return_obj;
    int size;
    string data;

    config_f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), sizeof(int)); // read string size
    vector<char> buff(size);
    config_f.read(buff.data(), size);
    data = string(buff.begin(), buff.end());
    return_obj.name = data;

    return return_obj;
}
```

As paddy pointed out directly and WhozCraig alluded to, this code still needs to implement a standardized, portable data type for recording the integer properly into binary and the write function needs to be rethought as well.

Thank you very much to the both of you. I read like 5-8 top search results for "cpp binary i/o" before writing my code and still ended up with that mess. You guys saved me hours/days of my life.